# Tableview scroll slow down due to Method call

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my tableview cell, there is a label for Description. The description text will be highlighted through Attributed Text in separate method. this method is call from `cellforRowIndexPath` & that's why tableview scroll is lagging a lot.

**My code**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
SearchVCCell *cell = (SearchVCCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SearchVCCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.lbl_title.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.lbl_disc.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.lbl_page.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page: %d",[[arrPageNumber objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]intValue]];


   int p= [self highlightText:_search_bar.text :cell.lbl_disc];   //Method Call
    cell.lbl_count.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",p];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**HightText Method:**

```
-(int) highlightText :(NSString *)srcTxt :(UILabel*)txtView {
    int srcTxtLen = srcTxt.length;
    int idx = 0,count=0;
    while (idx<(txtView.text.length-srcTxtLen)) {
        NSRange srcRange = NSMakeRange(idx, srcTxtLen);
        if ([[txtView.text substringWithRange:srcRange] isEqualToString:srcTxt]) {
            NSMutableAttributedString *tmpAttrTxt = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:txtView.attributedText];
            [tmpAttrTxt addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:srcRange];
            txtView.attributedText = tmpAttrTxt;
            idx += srcTxtLen;
            count++;
        } else {
            idx++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Help me to solve, Thanks in advance**

Comment: There must be some problem in your highlightText: : Method, can you add your highlightText: : Method here

Comment: @Anuj, I added my method.

Comment: did you doing change the color of your whole text?

Comment: Hey the problem is that - highlight: : method has if clause which will called for the (length of description text - length of highlighting text) times. This is why your tableview scroll slow.

Comment: @Anuj, I know about this. but what is the solution of this? How can I use block for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can replace your method call with this

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:cell.lbl_disc.text];
NSRange range=[cell.lbl_disc.text rangeOfString:_search_bar.text];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:range];
[self.textToSpeak setAttributedText:string];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But what about counter of string matching?

Comment: sorry but where is count?

Comment: what count? can you please tell what you want?

Comment: means occurance of string matching like count variable in my method.

Comment: it only matching string with first occurrence only. not all. really Bad!

Comment: so i post the second answer which match the all occurence

Answer (score 0):

use this method:

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString*) setColor:(UIColor*)color forWord:(NSString*)word inText:(NSMutableAttributedString*)string {

    NSUInteger count = 0, length = [string length];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);

    while(range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = [[string string] rangeOfString:word options:0 range:range];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
            [string setTextColor:color range:NSMakeRange(range.location, [word length])];
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
            count++;
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

and in your tableview cell call this

```
cell.lbl_disc.text=    [self setColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forWord:_search_bar.text inText:[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];
```

Comment: it slows more than previous.